# How do I do an exact phrase search on python using the twitter API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I'm writing a program in python that prints the usernames of the people who tweet either "I am happy", "I am sad", "I am angry", etc.

```
emotionList = ["happy", "sad", "angry"... (many more)]

for type in emotionList:

    #append the emotion to "I'm feeling"
    query = '\"I feel ' + type + '\"'

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, lang="en").items():
        print(api.get_user(tweet.user.id).screen_name, tweet.text)
```

Even though I use the double quotes (\") around the search string ("I feel" + a string in the list), the search is by relevance, not by the exact keyword. How do I search by the exact keyword?

Comment: You don't need to use \ in this case, but it is strange as twitter api should consider this as exact phrase for sure.

Comment: From: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets  q must be URL-encoded. "A UTF-8, URL-encoded search query of 500 characters maximum, including operators. Queries may additionally be limited by complexity." What happens if you use '\"I%20feel%20' instead of '\"I feel ' ?